# C - RGBA Conversion Not Returning The Desired RGB Result

Tags: c, gcc, rgb, data-conversion, rgba

Okay, I have a method that I am having a difficult time with returning the desired results. So I made a test result, and it is returning a result that I was not expecting.

Here is an example -->

```
int color = 0x00FFFF00;

return 0xFF & (color >> 24) | 0xFF & (color >> 16) | 0xFF & (color >> 8);
```

From what I know, this should return:

```
0x00FFFF
```

However, it actually returns:

```
0x0000FF
```

Can someone please explain what is happening? I would also like to know how I could properly convert the 32-bit RGBA integer to the 24-bit RGB integer, thank you.

Comment: On each shift you apply & 0xFF therefore there is only one valuable byte, others are zeroes.

Comment: I know. I was trying to get the specific color values within the RGBA integer and cast them to a RGB integer, however, clearlight already helped me with this one. I also see what I did wrong here anyhow. I should have shifted the results of the red and green elements to match the RGB integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

        unsigned int x = 0x00FFFF00;
        printf("0%8.8x", (x >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF);
}

$ cc -o shft shft.c
$ ./shft
0x0000ffff
```

It's better if you make color an `unsigned int`,
otherwise you can get the sign bit shifted in from the left, but in this case we're masking off the shifted in bytes, but be careful of that.

Answer (score 1):

I also caught what I did wrong. I was not shifting the red and green elements of the integer cast to match the RGB integer --->

```
int color = 0x00FFFF00;

// Returns 0x0000FF
return 0xFF & (color >> 24) | 0xFF & (color >> 16) | 0xFF & (color >> 8);
```

Here is the fixed code --->

```
unsigned int color = 0x00FFFF00; // Unsigned Integer to avoid shifting the Two's Complement flag into the RGB value as clearlight pointed out.

// Returns 0x00FFFF
return (0xFF & (color >> 24)) << 16 | (0xFF & (color >> 16)) << 8 | 0xFF & (color >> 8);
```